# Which lists are eligable for Quick charts

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part, modern-experience, chart-web-part

I have a SharePoint communication site, which contain 16 custom lists and 6 document libraries, but when I tried to create a chart using the modern Charts web part, I only get 3 lists inside the List drop-down:

[image]

So which SharePoint lists are eligible for quick charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select **Get data from a SharePoint list on this site** option in quick charts web part, SharePoint retrieves lists from current site using below endpoint:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists?$filter=(BaseTemplate ne 101) and (BaseTemplate ne 119) and (Hidden eq false)&$select=Id,Title,DefaultViewUrl
```

That means all the list types except Document library (101) & WebPageLibrary(119) and lists which are not hidden should be shown in **List** dropdown in quick charts web part.

**Reference**: [ListTemplateType enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541191(v=office.15))

---

Also, I have noticed that dropdown is showing only the lists which has at least one Number/Currency column.

> The list should have at least one text and one number or currency type column, else the list will not appear in the dropdown list.

Comment: thanks for the reply... when i run the url `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists?$filter=(BaseTemplate ne 101) and (BaseTemplate ne 119) and (Hidden eq false)&$select=Id,Title,DefaultViewUrl` i will get all the lists.. but inside the "List" drop-down only 3 out of 16 will be shown.. could the reason be that the lists inside the "List" drop-down should have at-least one column of type Number?

Comment: Yes, I was about to mention this >> see my updated answer.

Comment: Please [mark this as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way. It will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.